# Embed an SVG with animation via Angular

Tags: angularjs, svg, gulp

I am trying to embed an SVG with Angular.js using `ng-include`. The SVG contains animations which are defined in the `defs` tag, so they are self-included.

Now, the problem is that the animation is regularly performed and works amazingly when I check it on my local environment with `gulp serve`, but the animation doesn't work in production or when I run the server with `gulp serve:dist`.

I tried to include the SVG in many different ways, with `img` tag, with `object`, etc... with no luck, every single time I run the server with production configuration, the SVG is loaded, but the animation is ignored. Anyone else who experienced this issue?

Comment: Did you check the contents of the svg being loaded into the browser after the dist task is run?  Haven't seen this but wonder if an html minifier or something else is munging the svg when you run that task, aside from plugin config is there anything different about how the site/backend/anything is setup?

Comment: @shaunhusain you are my hero, yeah the SVG was correctly loading, but the minifying process was messing completely the whole SVG, turning the content of the style tag invalid. The trick is to skip SVGs files when gulp is minifying for prod, can you turn it into an answer so I can accept it?.

Comment: Ah sure lucky guess :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double check the svg sent by the browser after the 'dist' task is run.  An HTML minifier can mess up svg files so if that's a part of the dist task try disabling it or making sure it isn't targeting SVG files.